# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{6}+1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The hint for this exercise is to use either the gamma or the beta function. I think that a substitution that leads me to the gamma function is probably the way to go because of the bounds of the integral, but I  still haven't found such a substitution. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^6}\,dx=\frac1{36}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{-5/6}\log(x)}{1+x}\,dx =\frac1{36}\left.\left(\frac{d}{dy}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^y}{1+x}\,dx\right)\right|_{y=-5/6}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let our integral be $ I$.
To evaluate this integral, define a function $ f : [0,+\infty) \mapsto \mathbb R$
$$ f(a)= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{1+x^6}\ \mathrm{d} x$$
Notice that
$$ \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a }f(a) \right|_{a=0} = I $$
Now, via the substitution $ x^6=t$,
$$ f(a)=\frac{1}{6}\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{t^{\frac{a+1}{6}-1}}{1+t}\ \mathrm{d} t $$

Via the definition of beta function
$$ B(a,b)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^{a+b}}\ \mathrm{d}x $$

$$ f(a)=\dfrac{1}{6}B\Bigl(\frac{a+1}{6},1-\frac{a+1}{6}\Bigr) $$

Using the relationship of beta and gamma function
$$ B(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

$$ f(a)=\dfrac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{a+1}{6}\Big)\Gamma\Big(1-\frac{a+1}{6}\Big)}{6}$$

Using Euler's reflection formula for Gamma function
$$ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\pi \csc(\pi z)$$

$$f(a)= \dfrac{\pi}{6}\csc\Big(\frac{\pi(a+1)}{6}\Big) $$
Differentiating with respect to $a$,
$$ f^{\prime}(a)= -\frac{\pi ^2}{36}\csc\Big(\frac{\pi(a+1)}{6}\Big)\cot\Big(\frac{\pi(a+1)}{6}\Big) $$
Finally putting $a=0$, we get
$$\boxed{\boxed{I=-\frac{\pi^2}{6\sqrt{3}} }} $$
Please accept the answer if you like it.

Comment: Really nice (+1)

Comment: Thanks, Laxmi. Can you describe your thought process to get this answer? (I have a test next week and I have to learn to spot patterns in this type of integrals)

Comment: @DougL the method I used is mostly useful in integrals with $\ln{x}$ in the numerator, and polynomial with single variable in the denominator. It would not matter the power of variable in numerator. Just define the function as I set it up, differentiate as many powers the logarithm has required. The most tricky thing will be setting the function, as you have to take in account the power of variable in numerator. For practice you can solve integrals of type
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{x^a\ln^b{x}}{1+x^c}$$ $b$ should be integer.